# Android source and AudioRecord multi-utilisation

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-source, android-build

I'm currently building an android custom rom, which will be only controlled by voice:
So I came across this portion of code in the android source :

```
// refuse 2 active AudioRecord clients at the same time except if the active input                         
// uses AUDIO_SOURCE_HOTWORD in which case it is closed.
```

In https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware_legacy/+/master/audio/AudioPolicyManagerBase.cpp line 997

I would like to know for which purpose it's done? hardware limitation?

Comment: did you ever implemented that splitter? can you give me some pointers to what you've done?

Comment: It's not in a finished state, but i can give you some info on it!

Comment: The answer writed by @michael is quite good, in the facts you'll have to modify the audioflinger (input part) to match the way the output works, then you'll have to modify the record architecture from hardware->codec->dispatch(audioflinger) to hardware->dispatch->codec

Comment: @Vlad if you want more info contact me at colliotv.epitech@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a playback scenario, multiple concurrent clients writing to the same output are handled by means of mixing, which is implemented in libaudioflinger.

To handle multiple concurrent clients in a recording scenario you'd need some sort of stream splitter that takes care of consuming audio buffers coming from the driver and feeding them to all the clients, and possibly perform resampling, mono/stereo conversion, etc. A vanilla Android implementation simply doesn't have a stream splitter (not the last time I looked anyway).
 When I worked at Sony we used a proprietary stream splitter on a few phones (the Xperia P, U, and Solo, IIRC), which allowed us to support multiple recording clients. So it is possible to do, but it's not trivial.

Comment: so if i want to begin my research, browsing and learning from libaudioflinger would be enough or should i look at another code which would be more useful?

Comment: libaudioflinger seems like a good place to add a stream splitter (the one we used was added there), so understanding the different parts of libaudioflinger and how it's connected to the audio HAL on the one hand, and the client APIs (e.g. `AudioRecord`) on the other is certainly a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Its anyone's guess why that became the policy. Maybe it underlies a decision that the API would limit or pre-empt additional clients owning the mic's output.

Does it really matter? If you want to spawn threads and provide each a split copy of the Array of raw PCM bytes in the mic's output buffer, you are free to do that.

Look at "audiotrack" [here](https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android/blob/master/src/fm/audioboo/application/FLACPlayer.java) for some background on a players use of a buffer.

then

implement one of the [callback's here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener.html) in your recorder's implementation , adding a split function on the buffers bytes. Then do whatever you want in your respective threads.